# How can create a link to redirect with post method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a link that redirect to a page with POST method of data.

Is there any simple function to do this with Jquery?

Some thing like below code (without redirect to page)

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function DoPost(id){
 $.post("http://www.jooyeshgar.dev/desktop/module.php?op=users&f=email", { fn: "read", time: id } );  //Your values here..
}
</script>
```

And

```
<a href='javascript:DoPost({$row_email['id']})'>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you basically want to submit a form using an `a` instead of a button (after you have populated it with some values).

The simplest (and pure javascript) solution is to have a `form` (hidden, because it contains no visible elements) on your page (or create and append one dynamically):

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" 
  action="http://www.jooyeshgar.dev/desktop/module.php?op=users&f=email">
  <input type="hidden" name="fn" value="read" />
  <input type="hidden" name="time" value="" />
</form>

<a href="#" onclick="return !!DoPost(/*your string*/);">Submit</a>
```

And in javascript:

```
function DoPost(id){
  var frm=document.getElementById('myform');
  frm.time.value=id; 
  frm.submit();
}
```

Then let the browser do it's work :) as it is that behavior you seem to want.
That is the basics, you could translate it into jQuery based on the above concept.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSP in your program do it as,

Have a form to get data from the user in JSP. And make the form method as **"post"**

Create a servlet with the name FormServlet and for the form action in jsp have it as **action="FormServlet"**

then from servlet use,

```
response.sendRedirect("nameofyourpage");
```

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

On success callback function of $.post you can replace url by using window.location.replace() method:

```
$.post("http://www.jooyeshgar.dev/desktop/module.php?op=users&f=email", { fn: "read", time: id }, function(){ window.location.replace('your url.'); } );
```

for ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Thanks, but it do these work separately, I want to show result response of post data.